# How to cascade try imports in a readable way

Tags: python, readability

I want to try to import a list of JSON parsing libraries in python, with precedence for item in the order of which they're tried. If I have the following json libraries `ajson`, `bjson`, ... I'd have to write something like

```
try:
    import ajson as json
except ImportError:
    try:
        import bjson as json
    except ImportError:
        try:
            import cjson as json
        except ImportError:
            ...
```

which is very unreadable. Is there a better way to do this like an if statement?

Comment: Just curious, *why* you would need to do this?

Comment: Because this a library component which needs to use json encoding/decoding. We want to use the fastest json libraries where they're available, but fallback to other ones as sensible defaults.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define a function that encapsulates this fallback behavior:

```
import importlib

def import_fallback(*modules):
  for m in modules:
    try:
      return importlib.import_module(m)
    except ImportError:
      continue
  raise ImportError("All fallback imports failed: {}".format(modules))

# You can use it like this
json = import_fallback("ajson", "bjson", "cjson")
```

Edit: There might be a downside from doing this. Some linters or static code analyzers might not know that you are importing these modules by running this function

Answer (score 1):

Instead of producing exceptions and catching them with `try` and `except`, you can simply filter the module names with the [`importlib.util.find_spec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.util.find_spec) function, which returns `None` if the given module name is not found, and then import the found module with `importlib.import_module`:

```
json = importlib.import_module(
    next(filter(importlib.util.find_spec, ("ajson", "bjson", "cjson")))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the libraries you want to import using `importlib`

```py
import importlib
libs = ["os", "sys", "json"]
for lib in libs:
    try:
        globals()[lib] = importlib.import_module(lib)
        break #if you don't want to keep importing once you imported a library successfully
    except:
        pass
```

Answer (score -3):

This seems to work:

```
for lib in ['ajson','bjson','cjson']:
    try:
        __import__(lib)
        print('Imported ' + lib)
        break
    except ImportError:
        continue
```